# npm not installing modules

Tags: node.js, express, npm

C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\express -> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express-generator\bin\express-cli.js

I started by installing npm install , but nothing was installed , it says:

> express-generator@4.16.1
>   updated 1 package in 0.437s

but nothing is there. I installed the packages as dependencies from `package.json`. I know what I want to use thus I copied them to the  `package.json` file and the ran npm install.

When I run npm install express generator it gives me

> :\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\express -> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express-generator\bin\express-cli.js

what is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `npm i express-generator -S`